# Getting throwable when setting StreamVolume

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to set volume programatically every 2 seconds till max.

```
    val streamMaxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    var currentVolume = 0
    timer = Timer()
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, currentVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND)
            currentVolume += 1
            if (currentVolume >= streamMaxVolume) this.cancel()
        }
    }, 0, 2000)
```

It works perfectly, except that I keep getting these throwables and I don't know why...

```
I/AudioManager: setStreamVolume, streamType:3 index:0 flags:4 java.lang.Throwable
        at android.media.AudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.java:1143)
        at primoz.com.alarmcontinue.views.alarm.broadcast.TriggeredAlarmActivity$increaseVolumeOverTime$1.run(TriggeredAlarmActivity.kt:113)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
I/AudioManager: setStreamVolume, streamType:3 index:1 flags:4 java.lang.Throwable
        at android.media.AudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.java:1143)
        at primoz.com.alarmcontinue.views.alarm.broadcast.TriggeredAlarmActivity$increaseVolumeOverTime$1.run(TriggeredAlarmActivity.kt:113)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
I/AudioManager: setStreamVolume, streamType:3 index:2 flags:4 java.lang.Throwable
        at android.media.AudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.java:1143)
        at primoz.com.alarmcontinue.views.alarm.broadcast.TriggeredAlarmActivity$increaseVolumeOverTime$1.run(TriggeredAlarmActivity.kt:113)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
```

Comment: Perhaps it's a permissions issue?

Comment: Do you need permission to change the volume? :/

Comment: Recently I've started noticing the same problem in my app. No explanation, just "java.lang.Throwable". I also have the same line (AudioManager.java:1143).